# Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty (overridden by if condition)

Tags: php

I am trying to do a requirement for my assessment which is "In a form, If a user uploads 1 or Multiple images, those images and other input information need to be stored in database. If the user chose to not upload any images, other input information need to be stored in database."

This is the result I got when I do it with my way but it is not perfect

> Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\WEB Assignment\phpserver.php on line 178

This is what I get from var_dump

```
array(5) { 
    ["ServiceSelected"]=> string(8) "Teaching" 
    ["SkillsRequirement"]=> array(1) { 
            [0]=> string(4) "None" 
            } 
    ["serviceLocation"]=> string(8) "Test NM4" 
    ["CreditAward"]=> string(2) "99" 
    ["CreateTaskSubmit"]=> string(0) "" 
} 

array(1) { 
    ["Image"]=> array(5) { 
            ["name"]=> array(1) { 
                    [0]=> string(0) "" 
            } 
            ["type"]=> array(1) { 
                    [0]=> string(0) "" 
            } 
            ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { 
                    [0]=> string(0) "" 
            } 
    ["error"]=> array(1) { 
            [0]=> int(4) 
            } 
    ["size"]=> array(1) { 
            [0]=> int(0) 
            } 
    } 
} 

array(1) { 
    ["Image"]=> array(5) { 
        ["name"]=> array(1) { 
            [0]=> string(0) "" 
        } 
        ["type"]=> array(1) { 
            [0]=> string(0) "" 
        } 
        ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { 
            [0]=> string(0) "" 
            } 
        ["error"]=> array(1) { 
            [0]=> int(4) 
            } 
        ["size"]=> array(1) { 
            [0]=> int(0) 
            } 
    } 
}
```

My First try which works with the multiple image uploads

```
foreach ($_FILES['Image']['tmp_name'] as $ui) {
    $imagesUploaded = base64_encode(file_get_contents($ui));
    mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO imagedb 
                                (UploadedImage,Task_ID) 
                        VALUES ('$imagesUploaded','$lastTaskId')");
}
```

Second try when I try to do it with condition which my assessment need

```
if ($_FILES['Image']['size'] == 0) {
    $NoImage = "C:/xampp/htdocs/WEB Assignment/image/NoImage.jpg";
    $imagesUploaded = base64_encode(file_get_contents($NoImage));
    mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO imagedb 
                                (UploadedImage,Task_ID) 
                        VALUES ('$imagesUploaded','$lastTaskId')");
} else {
    foreach ($_FILES['Image']['tmp_name'] as $ui) {
        $imagesUploaded = base64_encode(file_get_contents($ui)); // Line 178
        mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO imagedb 
                                    (UploadedImage,Task_ID) 
                            VALUES ('$imagesUploaded','$lastTaskId')");
    }
}
```

Third try with different method

```
if (count($_FILES['Image']) > 0) {
        foreach ($_FILES['Image']['tmp_name'] as $ui) {
            $imagesUploaded = base64_encode(file_get_contents($ui)); // Line 178
            mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO imagedb (UploadedImage,Task_ID) VALUES ('$imagesUploaded','$lastTaskId')");
        }
    }else{
        echo "no image uploaded";
    }
```

The problem with ^ that is, whenever I didn't upload any image, I want the $NoImage stored into the database to show there is no image uploaded by the user but instead $NoImage is not stored into the database and "Warning" stuff is produced.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201967/discussion-on-question-by-wan-choon-warning-file-get-contents-filename-canno).

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

Modifying the 1st method to this

```
foreach ($_FILES['Image']['name'] as $ui => $value){
        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['Image']['tmp_name'][$ui])){
            $imagesUploaded = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['Image']['tmp_name'][$ui]));
            mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO imagedb (UploadedImage,Task_ID) VALUES ('$imagesUploaded','$lastTaskId')");
        }

    }
```